# Measuring the performance cost of std::function

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I'm trying to measure the performance cost of std::function vs C-Function pointers. I want to know if my measuring technique is fair to both for this particular function (decibels, see below).

To test the following measurements, I recompiled the program for N 1 to 6 (see below) and toggled the commented std::function vs raw function pointer.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

typedef float (*twoArgFuncPtr)(float, float);

//function name and signature
typedef float (*twoArgFuncPtr)(float, float);   
//a function matching the signature of the typedef function
float decibels(float p1, float p2)  
{
    return (float)log(p2 / p1);
}
int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock high_resolution_clock;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds;
    twoArgFuncPtr fnc= decibels;
    std::function<float(float,float)> fncObj= decibels;
    const int numLoops= 1000000*1; //re-compiled for 1000000 * to N=6
    high_resolution_clock::time_point start= high_resolution_clock::now();
    float result=0;
    for(int i=1, j=numLoops; i < numLoops-1; i++, j--)
    {
        //toggle the comment between the next two lines
        result+= fnc((float)i, (float)j);       //call by raw ptr
        //result+= fncObj((float)i, (float)j); //call by obj //uncomment this line to test std::function
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point end= high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<"Time in seconds: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-start).count()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Result: "<<result<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following timings:

[image]

On average, raw function pointers were 2.6 times faster than std::function. Was my timing fair to std::function or the raw func ptr?

edit:
I turned off optimizations
Compiled with Visual Studio 2012
Core i5 windows server 64bit

edit#2:
I am providing full optimization timings per request:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I got much less difference with g++ and clang++. At most about 10%. Did you turn on optimization?

Comment: By the way, wrap the code in your main in a function template so that you can run both tests in main without having to edit and recompile.

Comment: I turned off optimizations (see edit) for the timings . Its 1.33 times faster on average if I turn them on.

Comment: In general, lead with your optimized results.  The speed of unoptimized code is less (but not completely un-) interesting.

Comment: 1.33 is still higher than I'm seeing, but within reason I suppose. I see a 3% increase in time with g++. If you are benchmarking for practical reasons (as opposed to educational), then it's more reasonable to turn on optimization since that is what would be done in actual release code. Of course, if you are benchmarking to learn, then turning them off may make sense.

Comment: It is interesting when full optimizations are turned on. There is little difference between them. I guess it is fair to say there is little performance penalty for using std::function. Any other suggestions? Btw, I'm doing this for my own research and will probably write an article in the near future about it.

Comment: The performance will vary. If you want to test a couple other use cases, test lambda and a functor with std::function. This will all be easier though if you wrap your test in a function template.

Comment: Both situations here make it reasonable that an optimizer might realize that `fnc` and `fncObj` always point at `decibels` and just simply call `decibels` directly.  If that happens, you'd be measuring something rather different from typical uses of function pointers and `std::function`.

Comment: @roboto1986: If you really want to learn, output the optimized assembly and look at that. If you are using Linux, use -S to do that. Run the assembly through c++filt to demangle. By doing this, you can definitively resolve aschepler's supposition.

Comment: @user3521733 thanks, I may make some modifications to test easier as long as it doesn't affect the timings.

Comment: I think I am heading in that route of examining assembly. That is a good point. Compiler may just be invoking the function ptr directly.

Comment: @roboto: If you make it a function template, then it won't affect the timings.

Comment: @roboto: Also, you can test an inline version. It's not realized, but inlining's effect is often just as much (if not more) about allowing the optimizer to kick-butt as it is as about function call cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The optimized version is more than fair to `std::function`.

`std::function` typical implementation is a type erased pImpl inner class that has a `virtual` invocation and copy interface.

This means the cost of calling a `std::function` is roughly that of a `virtual` method call, plus the original invocation.

In theory `std::function` could optimized the pointer-to-identical signature function case (and the function-pointer to function-pointer case for tyoe conversion wrapping a function pointer).

The significant extra hit on `std::function` would be if the `virtual` method table was out of the cache.  This is unlikely to occur in your test, but reasonably likely to occur in actual real world use cases.  Hence more than fair.